# Jquery alpha numeric sorting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I am trying to get the immediate childs(li) for top Parent(ul). But I am getting all the inner and inner level children(li).

Structure

```
<ul id="top_parent">
     <li>xyz</li>
     <li>xyz</li>
           <ul>
                <li> abc </li>
           </ul>
     <li>xyz</li>
     <li>xyz</li>

</ul>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
var elems = $('#top_parent').children('li');
```

Can anybody suggest me how can i get the immediate children only.

Comment: `children()` gives the direct childrens only

Comment: children should search only one level down.

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect: You have an UL as direct child of another UL.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/children/) `.children()` should do exactly what you want:

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

I.e.,

```
$("#top_parent").children("li")
```

is the same as

```
$("#top_parent > li")
```

Here is the code snippet which demonstrates that this method works as expected.
Only children `li`s are being colored green:

```js
var elems = $('#top_parent').children('li');

elems.css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top_parent">
     <li>xyz</li>
     <li>xyz</li>
           <ul>
                <li> abc </li>
           </ul>
     <li>xyz</li>
     <li>xyz</li>
</ul>
```

It looks like the problem is somewhere else in your code but not at this line.

Comment: `children` does the same thing